# Grouping in PHP using a character

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
    array{
     0 => string 'B.E - ECE',
     1 => string 'B.E - EEE',
     2 => string 'Msc - Maths',
     3 => string 'Msc - Social',
}
```

So how can I make the array into groups like:

```
B.E. => ECE, EEE
Msc => Maths,Social
```

?

I want to do it in PHP. Can anybody help me how to achieve it ?

Comment: Show a dump of your actual array, not simply a string of characters, otherwise it's very hard to visualise what you're saying

Comment: Give your array structure ....! So that we can help you

Comment: @WinterBash Thats a string actually how i have written in question

Comment: @MarkBaker there is a string i will enter & output will be in array of groups

Comment: @MarkBaker As per you want i given array....now can we group it like B.E & Msc etc

Comment: Ria Dev, please can you clarify - is your array an array or a string? And are you intending to get the outcome as key=>value pairs as you have put in your "group arrays" sentence? Your question is a little contradictory, probably by a blurring of meanings.

Comment: @Martin can u group the array i have written in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is your array split by the "-" character?

so it's `Key` - `Value` pairs split by commas?

Ok -

(edit: section removed to clarify answer)

Following conversation and some rearrangement of the question, a second try at a solution, with the above assumptions, try this:

```
$array = array {
     0 => string 'B.E - ECE' (length=9)
     1 => string 'B.E - EEE' (length=9)
     2 => string 'Msc - Maths' (length=11)
     3 => string 'Msc - Social' (length=12)
}


foreach ($array as $row){
$piece = explode("-",$row);
$key = $piece[0];
$newArray[$key][] = $piece[1];
unset($piece);
}
unset($row) ///tidy up
```

This will output two arrays each of two arrays:

```
$newArray[Msc] = array("Maths","Social");
$newArray[B.E] = array("ECE","EEE");
```

What I did was cause the Foreach loop to automatically add onto the array if the key exists with `$newArray[$key][]` so that the values are automatically collected by key, and the key is defined as the first half of the original array values.

### Printing:

To print the result:

```
foreach($newArray as $key=>$newRow){
/// there are two rows in this case, [B.E] and [MSc]
print $key.":<br>";
print "<pre>";
///<pre> HTML tag makes output use linebreaks and spaces. neater.
print_r($newRow);
///alternatively use var_dump($newRow);
print "</pre>";
}
```

Alternatively if you wish to print a known named variable you can write:

```
print_r($newArray['B.E']);
```

Which will print all the data in that array. print_r is very useful.

Comment: I am giving the strings...on dump its coming as an array i shown in my question. Now i need to group it by B.E,Msc etc

Comment: How can i print the values can u please tell me ?

Comment: I really would recommend doing some basic PHP research via PHP.net and Google. . . . . . But to print the values, use foreach loops, and print what you need. Foreach is your best-friend for dealing with arrays.

Comment: Okay i will proceed but i m new to PHP so that i asked you. Actually i need to print both B.E. & its elements. Can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

what you want is php's explode. Not sure if this will give you the perfect answer but should give you an idea of what to do next.

```
$groupedArray = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    $split = explode(" - ",$row);
    $groupedArray[] = $split[0];
}
array_unique($groupedArray); //This will give you the two groupings

foreach($array as $row){
    $split = explode(" - ",$row);
    $pos = array_search($split[0],$groupedArray);
    if($pos !== FALSE){
        $groupedArray[$pos][] = $split[1];
    }
}
```

This should give you a full formatted array called `$groupedArray` where $array is the array you already have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Before everything we should explode by comma

Comment: errm, if it's an array as you have stated then you shouldn't need to explode by comma. Your comments on this thread are causing at least me more confusion than clarity.

Comment: see i given one string on dump i am getting the array i written in question...To that array i applied your solution its coming empty

Comment: At least can you group the array i shown in question

Comment: @RIADev There is no need for me to explode by comma since an array is given. like I said, it may not be the perfect answer but it should help .